# Running Spark Slave on Windows

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have got a Spark master up and running on http 192.168.1.52:4040 on one computer on my network. When I try to connect a slave on another computer using this master url and / or using spark instead of http the slave wont start. When I visit http 192.168.1.52:4040 on the second computer the web UI works perfectly.

This is the command I am using:

.sbin>start-slave.sh http://192.168.1.52:4040

or

using spark:// instead of http://

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I have also tried running by replacing the host IP with the same computer's host name. Again the web UI works but the slave won't start.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to get it up and running. The documentation mentions the following for Windows computers:

> To run a Spark cluster on Windows, start the master and workers by
>   hand.

I had to run

```
\spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6\bin>spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master
```

and

```
\spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6\bin>spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://192.168.56.1:7077
```

to run the Master and Workers respectively.